# strange Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class paradox

Tags: php

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysql' not found in /home/o
```

So naturally I include the class, but when I do I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
```

As you can imagine I have no idea how to fix this problem!!

Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: Try using include_once instead of include to ensure that the file isn't included a second time.

Comment: You don't "include" classes. And without seeing your code, as you can imagine, we have no idea how to fix it either.